# Angular 6 - NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, typescript

Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

**I have model:**

```js
import { Classroom } from "./classroom.model";

export class Student {
    public id : string;
    public name: string;
    public classroom: Classroom[];
    public mother: string;  
    public phone_mother: string; 
    public father: string;    
    public phone_father: string;
    public address: string;

    constructor(id : string, name: string, classroom: Classroom[], mother: string, phone_mother: string, father: string,  phone_father: string, address: string, ){
        this.id = id,
        this.name = name;
        this.mother = mother;
        this.father = father;
        this.phone_mother = phone_mother;
        this.phone_father = phone_father;
        this.address = address;
        this.classroom = classroom;
    }
}
```

**My Service:**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Student } from "../models/student.model";
import { Classroom } from "../models/classroom.model";

@Injectable()
export class StudentsServices
 {   
    private _url = 'https://localhost:3000/api/aluno'
       
    constructor(private http: Http){}

getStudents(){
    return this.http
                .get(this._url)
                .pipe(map((response : Response) => {
                    return <Student[]>response.json();
                }));                         
}


    getEstudantes(): Observable<Student[]> {
        return this.http.get(this._url)
                        .pipe(map(res=>res.json()));                        
     } 

}
```

**My Component:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { StudentsServices } from '../services/students.services';
import { Student } from '../models/student.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-students',
  templateUrl: './students.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./students.component.css'],
  providers: [StudentsServices]
})
export class StudentsComponent implements OnInit {  
  _students: Student[] = [];  

  constructor(private services: StudentsServices) { }

  getStudents(): void {
        this.services.getStudents()
                     .subscribe(
                        data => this._students = data,
                        error => console.log("Student Service Error: " + error)
                     )
  }  

  getEstudantes() {
    this.services.getUsers()
                    .subscribe(
                      data => this._students = data,
                      error =>  console.log("Student Service Error: " + error));
  }

  ngOnInit() {    
        this.getStudents();

        //this.getEstudantes();

        console.log(this._students);
  }
}
```

**and this is my HTML**

```js
<div class="row">
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">ID</th>
                <th class="text-center">Nome</th>
                <th class="text-center">Mãe</th>
                <th class="text-center">Pai</th>
                <th class="text-center">Telefone da mãe</th>
                <th class="text-center">Telefone do Pai</th>
                <th class="text-center">Endereço</th>
                <th class="text-center">Turma</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let student of _students">
                <td class="text-center">{{student.id}}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{student.name}}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{student.mother}}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{student.father}}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{student.phone_father}}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{student.phone_mother}}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{student.address}}</td>
                
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**these are the data**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tenta let student of _student.alunos

Comment: Já tentei, diz que alunos não existe ):

Comment: Faz um demon no stackblitz

Comment: por favor não poste imagem como código. Tem como vc editar sua pergunta com o código em si?

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485

Comment: Se postar seu código como texto eu faço um stackblitz e vejo o que há de errado.

Comment: Alterei para código, se conseguir me ajudar.

Comment: O que sai quando vc joga a url no Browser? Tem como adicionar um print?

Comment: {"alunos":[{"_id":"5b0af0b3539af000143a39af","nome":"Adriano","turma":{"_id":"5b0aee26539af000143a39ab","descricao":"TURMA 304"}},{"_id":"5b0af0b7539af000143a39b0","nome":"Tais","turma":{"_id":"5b0aee26539af000143a39ab","descricao":"TURMA 304"}},{"_id":"5b0af0bb539af000143a39b1","nome":"Gustavo","turma":{"_id":"5b0aee26539af000143a39ab","descricao":"TURMA 304"}},{"_id":"5b0af0be539af000143a39b2","nome":"Vinicius","turma":{"_id":"5b0aee26539af000143a39ab","descricao":"TURMA 304"}}],"total":4}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O meu problema estava no mapeamento dos dados que vinham da api para as variáveis que estavam na minha model. Na api os dados estavam vindo em português e na minha model estava em inglês.

Assim consegui especificar qual dado eu queria na chamada do meu serviço "data.alunos":

```js
getStudents(): void {
        this.services.getStudents()
                     .subscribe(
                        data => this._students = data.alunos,
                        error => console.log("Student Service Error: " + error),
                        () => console.log('Done.')
                     )
  }
```

Precisei ajustar o serviço também:

```js
  getStudents(){
        return this.http
                    .get(this._url)
                    .pipe(map((response => response.json())));                         
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta inicializar a variavel students quando vc a declara:

```
_students:Student[]= []

this.services.getStudents()
.pipe(map(student=>student.alunos))
.subscribe(alunos=>this._students=alunos)
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema está na assincronissidade dos processos, o seu codigo no .html esta sendo executando antes mesmo de conseguir alimentar a variavel dentro do seu .ts. Para esse problema voce precisa trabalhar com promessas ou Promise. um exemplo

Metodo dentro do serviço:

```
public getProjetos(): Promise<Projeto[]>{
return this.http.get(`${this.url_api}projetos/`)
.toPromise()
.then((resposta: any) => {
    console.log("Teste: " + resposta)
    return resposta.json()
})
```

chamada do serviço:

```
this.projetoService.getProjetos().then((projetos: Projeto[]) => {
  this.projetos = projetos

})
```

Comment: Opa é Angular 6, não AngularJS

Comment: isso, essa prática tambem serve para Angular 6, solucionei o problema com Promise, mas você pode solucionar com observable, mas eu ainda não domino essa pratica